# I want to find how to use an if statement on a randomly generated number in a range

Tags: python

This is what I have so far

```
x = print(randint(1,75))

if x == "1":

    print("Yes")
```

But my code does not return "yes"

Comment: Because "1" is a string. Use `if x == 1:` (without the quotes). PD: Also you should assign `x =  randint(1,75)` (without the print)

Comment: Okay thank you will try it now

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning to x the value returned from the print function, and not the randint value, which means it will never be == "1".

Try this:

```
x = randint(1,75)
print(x)
if x == 1:
    print("Yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should be:

```
from random import randint

x = randint(1,75) # You cannot assign a print statement to a variable 
if x == 1: # "1" is a string and 1 is a integer.
    print("Yes")
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it answered your question :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't use print to assign to X. 
The print function does not return a value, so while you are printing the random number, x = None. 
Therefore you should separate the two like this:

```
x = randint(1,75)
print(x)
```

Additionally, randint() generates an integer, not a string. Therefore you cannot compare x using "". You should try this:

```
if x == 1:
    print("Yes")
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to this

```
x = randint(1, 75)
if x == 1:
    print('Yes')
```